# Trello and card change log

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is there a way to see when a Trello card description was last edited and by whom? Or any details such as these?

Answer (score 1):

**AFAIK this is currently not possible.**

A **workaround** is to always post a comment on a card when an important update to the description is made. Depending on the gravity of the edit, it can be useful to include the old card description in the comment.